# Saving a set of strings using stylized fonts to MariaDB with strange results

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb

I currently have MariaDB version 10.4.18 on CentOS 8.0. When I'm trying to save a string with stylized fonts like below,

MariaDB saved them as "??? ????"

The statement

```
mysql> insert into testings(test) values (' ');
```

Here is my database's charset and collation

```
mysql> select @@collation_database;

+----------------------+
| @@collation_database |
+----------------------+
| utf8mb4_unicode_ci   |
+----------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT @@character_set_database;   
+--------------------------+
| @@character_set_database |
+--------------------------+
| utf8mb4                  |
+--------------------------+
```

The table

```
mysql> SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM testings;
+-------+------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+---------------------------------+---------+
| Field | Type | Collation          | Null | Key | Default | Extra | Privileges                      | Comment |
+-------+------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+---------------------------------+---------+
| test  | text | utf8mb4_unicode_ci | NO   |     | NULL    |       | select,insert,update,references |         |
+-------+------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+---------------------------------+---------+
```

Can anyone point me to right direction?

Comment: Check connection charset/collation - it is applied to the text literals. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=a7b542610ee715845274950404d2f964

Comment: @Akina ahh I see, I setup my collation_connection, character_set_client, character_set_results,  character_set_system to utf8mb4 and it works! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Answered by @Akina, I edited my database config with parameters below

```
SET collation_connection = 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci';
SET character_set_client = 'utf8mb4';
SET character_set_results = 'utf8mb4';
SET character_set_system = 'utf8mb4';
```

Now it works!